# How to only have one database instance combined with ajax

Tags: php

I know similar question has been asked before, but not together with ajax like this... 
So i've tried dependency injection for my database class, and red guides (for example https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes) that states that one connection instance of the database should be made and passed around to all classes/functions...

The problem is, how to do it when I make post with ajax from Index.php to myfunctions.php... I think the problem lies here:

```
$database = new Database();
$conn = $database->getConnection();
```

It doesn't matter if I instanciate it in Database.php because even if I have "require_once" each ajax call will run it... (validated with a simple test to print out log messages from the constructor in Database class)

**Database.php**

```
<?php

class Database 
{
    private $host = "";
    private $db_name = "";
    private $username = "";
    private $password = "";
    private $conn;


    function __construct()
    {
        $this->host = "localhost";
        $this->db_name = "mydb";
        $this->username = "user";
        $this->password = "pass";           
    }


    public function getConnection()
    {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }   
}
?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    // start session, and check for valid login
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
// all HTML including bind jquery ajax calls to functions.php
$.ajax({ method: "POST", url: "myfunctions.php", }) ... and so on
```

**MyFunctions.php**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

require_once "database.php";

$database = new Database();
$conn = $database->getConnection();

MyFunctions::start();


class MyFunctions
{
    public static function start()
    {
       // Do stuff... 
       $stmt = $conn... // and so on
    }
//....
```

Comment: _“that states that one connection instance of the database should be made and passed around to all classes/functions”_ - that was probably meant within the scope of one request … But with AJAX, you have a new request each time.

Comment: @04FS Yes that is the problem... I'm used to working with ajax so therefore I use it.. Maybe it's a design flaw from my side?

Comment: Every PHP script which you intend to call with AJAX should instantiate the **Database** class and use its connection.

Comment: @IVOGELOV That's how I do it today, look at `MyFunctions.php`

Comment: Then the question does not make sense to me. When you request the page the web server executes the INDEX.PHP, sends the result to browser and then forgets about it. Later, when your page makes an AJAX request to API_ENDPOINT.PHP - the web server executes this script and sends the result to the browser. Each of these 2 PHP scripts should create a **Database** object and use its connection.

Comment: There is no other way of doing it. But remember PHP will internally pool connections and reuse then where possible

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok, I was hoping that PHP actually did that. So it's no issue then?

Comment: Not one you can solve from PHP, no